# Use static data between angular component

Tags: angular, static, routes

In a localhost angular project i would like to have two routed component working on the same data: one to show the data, and the other to manage the data.

In other words i would like to have two webpages: in the first page a have an input to insert data in an array, in the second page i only show this (or these) array/s

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this in a few ways. Here are two.

Use a service with an observable. Add the data in one component and access it in the other.
https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

OR

Be lazy and put both views in the same component and use ngIf to toggle. (Since this is a local project)